# Android Studio Not Prompting Device on Run

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to run my application on either an emulator or my device. When I click the "run" button at the top of Android Studio, the app is not running but simply listing the message below:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java "-Dgradle.home=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1" -Dtools.jar=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar -Didea.launcher.port=7533 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/groovy-all-2.4.4.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/ant-1.9.6.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/ant-launcher-1.9.6.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/gradle-base-services-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/gradle-base-services-groovy-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/gradle-cli-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/gradle-core-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/gradle-docs-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/gradle-installation-beacon-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/gradle-jvm-services-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/gradle-launcher-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/gradle-logging-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/gradle-messaging-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/gradle-model-core-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/gradle-model-groovy-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/gradle-native-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/gradle-open-api-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/gradle-process-services-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/gradle-resources-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/gradle-tooling-api-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/gradle-ui-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/gradle-wrapper-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/plugins/gradle-announce-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/plugins/gradle-antlr-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/plugins/gradle-build-comparison-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/plugins/gradle-build-init-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/plugins/gradle-code-quality-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/plugins/gradle-dependency-management-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/plugins/gradle-diagnostics-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/plugins/gradle-ear-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/plugins/gradle-ide-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/plugins/gradle-ide-native-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/plugins/gradle-ide-play-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/plugins/gradle-ivy-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/plugins/gradle-jacoco-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/plugins/gradle-javascript-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/plugins/gradle-jetty-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/plugins/gradle-language-groovy-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/plugins/gradle-language-java-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/plugins/gradle-language-jvm-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/plugins/gradle-language-native-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/plugins/gradle-language-scala-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/plugins/gradle-maven-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/plugins/gradle-osgi-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/plugins/gradle-platform-base-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/plugins/gradle-platform-jvm-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/plugins/gradle-platform-native-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/plugins/gradle-platform-play-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/plugins/gradle-plugin-development-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/plugins/gradle-plugin-use-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/plugins/gradle-plugins-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/plugins/gradle-publish-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/plugins/gradle-reporting-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/plugins/gradle-resources-http-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/plugins/gradle-resources-s3-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/plugins/gradle-resources-sftp-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/plugins/gradle-scala-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/plugins/gradle-signing-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/plugins/gradle-sonar-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/plugins/gradle-test-kit-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/plugins/gradle-testing-base-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/plugins/gradle-testing-jvm-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/plugins/gradle-testing-native-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/plugins/gradle-tooling-api-builders-2.14.1.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/lib/plugins/ivy-2.2.0.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain --build-file /Users/troychuinard/Code/FanPolls/app/build.gradle
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:help

Welcome to Gradle 2.14.1.

To run a build, run gradle <task> ...

To see a list of available tasks, run gradle tasks

To see a list of command-line options, run gradle --help

To see more detail about a task, run gradle help --task <task>

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 8.841 secs

This build could be faster, please consider using the Gradle Daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The prompt is never appearing that asks me to select a deployment target. What is the setting in Android Studio to enable?

Comment: try to update gradle and JDK and try again

Comment: looks like some missconfiguration in your gradle. Try re-importing your project

Comment: how do you re-import?

Answer (score 5):

To enable the `Deployment Target Dialog` go to `Run -> Edit Configuration -> Android App (app) -> Target: Open Select Deployment Target Dialog`

Besides that you also have to enable `developer mode` on your device and have the drivers installed via the SDK manager or the manufacturer.

To check if your device is recognized you can use `adb devices` and it should be listed.

The `adb` is located under the `platform-tools` e.g.

```
C:\Users\You\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the android build tools version 25.0.0 resolves this issue, I was previously using 25.0.1 and it was not loading the device chooser:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
}
```

Anyone able to run with the latest build tools?